# Can we change the tour page to have a non-unicorn question?

Tags: discussion, tour

If you go to [the tour page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) today, you'll see information specific to this site as well as an example question about unicorns:

[image: Unicorn question on Christianity SE Tour]

In contrast, [Mi Yodeya's tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) has a question specific to Judaism.

Can we have an example question related to Christianity, rather than one about unicorns?

Comment: There was actually a [small discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26651933#26651933) about this a while ago. Presently, our only option at this point is [What is the difference between belief and faith, from a Protestant perspective?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20278/what-is-the-difference-between-belief-and-faith-from-a-protestant-perspective), which isn't ideal for a couple reason. (One being that there's a character limit on what questions and answers can be shown, and short questions/answers aren't the best for us.)

Comment: Why is that question our only option?

Comment: It's the only question where the question and at least two answers are short enough.

Comment: Unicorns and daisies are a thing of the past ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [El'endia commented](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6134/can-we-change-the-tour-page-to-have-a-non-unicorn-question#comment14678_6134) there is currently [only one candidate](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20278/what-is-the-difference-between-belief-and-faith-from-a-protestant-perspective) for this right now and it's not a good choice. It really doesn't show off what answers *should* look like on this site. Most notably the answers that would show up are not explicitly scoped to match the question. As that's the one point new users have the hardest time coming to grips with I think it's essential that we highlight it on any example posts.

At this point the only idea I have is to contrive an example by composing it here on meta with community consensus, then posting it on main, getting it the votes it needs to qualify, then locking it so it doesn't get messed up. To this end I would suggest finding some good existing Q&A that **is** really representative of the site and edit it down to a short summary of its initial self.

**Edit:** The Unicorns are gone! Please feel free to still [chip in here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6136/30) if there are any further suggestions for refining this.

Comment: I was wondering if we'd need to construct a question. I would be in favor of doing that. Should we post a new meta topic about that or just handle it in here?

Comment: @Thunderforge Lets post suggested mockups as answers to [this question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6136/30).